# How to replace uppercase and lowercase with regex in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I'm trying to create a regex replacement pattern for some text in MemoQ, a translation software, but `\L` and `\l` end up written in the replaced text.

I'm basically trying to replace structures like "Press 1 if want to do this." to "If you want to do this, press 1".

The regex I came up with for Spanish text is:

```
(Oprima|Presione|Pulse)\s*(el)*\s*([0-9])\s((.)*?)\.
```

And the replacement I'm using is:

```
$4, $1 $3.
```

For example, for "Oprima 1 si quiere hacer su pago por teléfono." I get "si quiere hacer su pago por teléfono, Oprima 1.", which is OK, but I need to get an uppercase in "si" and a lowercase in "Oprima" so it's in proper sentence format.

I tried to use `\L` and `\l` before the respective `$`, but MemoQ writes `\L` and `\l` along with the replaced sentence, so it seems those escaped tokens are not working here. I checked MemoQ's help section on regex, but they only mention replacement functions very simply, nothing to make this sort of modification.

Any ideas of what other thing instead of `\l` or `\L` I can use to replace uppercase and lowercase letters?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that we'd facing many edge cases, yet if we wish to just start with an expression, we can likely try:

```
([A-Z].+[0-9]+)\s*([a-z])(.+)([.;,:])
```

Or:

```
(.+[0-9]+)\s*(.)(.+)([.;,:])
```

For lower/uppercasing, we might want to use JavaScript built-in functions, `\U$2\L$3, \L$1$4` would be just for demoing:

#### [Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/0ivhk4/1/)

Here, it might be best we would split the sentences, script most of our problem instead of solving the entire problem with regular expressions.

For instance, I'm not sure about `\U` and `\L` in JavaScript, `.tolowercase` and `.touppercase` functions might be simply much suitable.

#### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/DPEnAA/1/)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for helping! I tried that expression, but the problem is that it also matches sentences that are OK, for example: "Oprima 1 si quiere hacer su pago por teléfono. Si quiere otra cosa, oprima 2."

 The first option I mentioned only matches the sentence that starts with "Oprima" and ignores the second one, which is what I need.

I also tried to use \U$4, \L$1 $3., but the "\U" and "\L" are written in the result, like "\Usi quiere hacer su pago por teléfono, \LOprima 1."